# How to solve: Error connecting to the service protocol: failed to connect to http://127.0.0.1

Tags: android

I have no errors and everything is updated, but still have this weird unsolvable problem. Tried almost everything, still not fixed. If any code of further information is required do let me know.

```
Launching lib\main.dart on AOSP on IA Emulator in debug mode...
Warning: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"base-extension"). Expected elements are <{}codename>,<{}layoutlib>,<{}api-level>
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
W/FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate( 6795): A splash screen was provided to Flutter, but this is deprecated. See flutter.dev/go/android-splash-migration for migration steps.
D/FlutterLocationService( 6795): Creating service.
D/FlutterLocationService( 6795): Binding to location service.
Error connecting to the service protocol: failed to connect to http://127.0.0.1:52964/fKZUd995YVM=/
Exited (sigterm)
```

Answer (score 2):

The specified IP address, i.e., `127.0.0.1`, is the IP address of your local host. If you're running your app using an android studio emulator, you need to change it to `10.0.2.2`.

If you want to connect your application to the server through an internet connection from any device, you need to buy an IP static.

Comment: I'd remove last sentence. it's usually more work than that if you want to be exposed to the outer word and it is not in scope of OP question

Comment: And how do you change it to 10.0.2.2 ?

Comment: In the same way you defined it should load the localhost, replace localhost with the above-mentioned IP address @Vesh